# HTML muliple select should look like HTML select

Tags: html, select

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a55fa98f01.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a55fa98f01.jpg)Hi I am trying to use a HTML select box with 'multiple' select options and size to 1 as below
`

```
<SELECT NAME="toppings" MULTIPLE SIZE=5>
<OPTION VALUE="mushrooms">mushrooms
<OPTION VALUE="greenpeppers">green peppers
</SELECT>
```

When the size is set to 1 small scrollbar appears which makes the page clumsy.If I increase the size its eating up my page since there are around 20 such multiple boxes in and around the page. I am looking for a solution which looks like `<SELECT>` but should function as multiple
Is this possible. I remember seen something similar but don't remember exactly.
Any ideas

I had uploaded the image[Sample http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a55fa98f01.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a55fa98f01.jpg)

Comment: sounds pretty counter-intuitive to have a dropdown that allows multiple selections.. unless you use checkboxes or something.. in which case you will need to use javascript ..

btw. it is not possible with just html/css

Comment: I think image is not loading perhaps image URL:http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a55fa98f01.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out this code](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list)... it turns your multi-row select into a dropdown with checkboxes using jQuery.

[code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list)

Comment: Updated link:  http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/. Demo is a link on that page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go in bit of a different direction with this one:

You really, *really* need to rethink your design if you need to do what you are doing here. You might also want to pick up a book on HTML; and interface design in general.

When things look a certain way, that gives people certain expectations: A single-select should *always* look like a single-select, and a multiple-select should *never* look like a single-select.

Comment: -1 because I disagree and therefore this isn't a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a multiple select to display as a regular select. If you could, how would you expect the user to select multiple values ?

That being said, the solution would be to create your own custom solution or use one of the jquery plugin out there.

Comment: You are right!But I am looking for a solution where CSS change makes the feel like single Select but serves as Muliple select. My 2 cents!!

Comment: @gustlywind Then see the second part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the scroll bar in a multi-select... otherwise it would look like a text-area and may confuse a user. If you really want to hide it, make a div and float it over the area of the scrollbar to simulate hiding it. I don't recommend it but its a possibility.