# How to have a collasped drop down list in rails simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

In my app, there are two models: rfq and standard. Their relationship is many-to-many. In rfq creating screen, the code below displays a list of available for selection in drop down list:

```
<%= simple_form_for @rfq do |f| %>    
<%= f.association :standards, :collection => Standard.active_std.all(:order => 'name'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id %> 
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the list is not collapsed, which means there are multiple standards displayed in a multi-line boxes. How can I reduce the box to one line only?

Thanks.

UPDATED: here is the screen shot of multiple line list box:
[image]

Comment: so, it creates multiple select for you, right? and you want not multiple select?

Comment: The regular drop down list has only one line. Mine spans over multiple lines and takes too much space on the screen.

Comment: so if the multiple select is a problem use this: `<%= f.association :standards, :collection => Standard.active_std.all(:order => 'name'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :input_html => { :multiple => false } %>`

Comment: still the same with addition of :input_html...

Comment: Just updated the post with a screen shot. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating a multi-select because one rfq can have many standards, so it allows you to ctrl-click to select many standards.

You could try adding `:input_html => { :size =>'1' }` but I'm not sure that will preserve the scrollbar.  It definitely won't drop down.

Here's someone else who wanted to do the same thing:  [HTML muliple select should look like HTML select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463055/html-muliple-select-should-look-like-html-select).  One of the answers refers to a [Dropdown Check List](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) implemented in jQuery, but that would take some work to integrate with SimpleForm.

SimpleForm has a very helpful Google Group--you might get more ideas there:

http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-simpleform

Answer (score 1):

You can add `as: :collection_select`

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
=f.collecion_select, model_associated_ids, collection, value, label
```

in your is like this

```
=f.collection_select, :standard_ids, Standard.active_std.all, :id, :name
```

you can find more info here

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form