# Can't get Dropdown Association to work with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using simple_form for my forms and I have a landing page which I have associated to a template. I'm trying to have a dropdown appear on the landing page form that lets the user select the template for the landing page and have the template names appear in the dropdown.

Here are my models:
landing_page.rb

```
class LandingPage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :template
    has_many :leads
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :template

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_presence_of :page_url
    validates_presence_of :template_id
    validates_presence_of :content

end
```

template.rb

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :landing_pages

    validates_presence_of :template_name
end
```

Here is my landing page form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@landing_page) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name, :input_html => {:maxlength =>50, :style=> 'width: 500px'} %>
    <%= f.input :title, :input_html => {:maxlength =>50, :style=> 'width: 500px'}, label: 'HTML Title'  %>
    <%= f.input :page_url, :input_html => {:maxlength =>50, :style=> 'width: 500px'}  %>
    <%= f.input :template_id, :input_html => {:maxlength =>50, :style=> 'width: 500px'} %>
    <%= f.input :content, :input_html => {:maxlength =>50, :style=> 'width: 500px'}  %>
  </div>
```

If I enter an integer for the template_id it's saved to the database correctly. However, I've tried every page I could find with examples and can't seem to make a dropdown (collection select) work for this field and have it display the template names in the dropdown.

I've looked at these pages:
http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form
[How to have a collasped drop down list in rails simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795268/how-to-have-a-collasped-drop-down-list-in-rails-simple-form)
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
<%= f.association :template, label_method: :template_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: true, :input_html => {:maxlength =>50, :style=> 'width: 500px'} %>
```